# how to break code into small chunks to make the code cleaner in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, clean-architecture

I have a profile page where I am using `PageController`.

Now the form have 3 to 4 set of sections which I want to extract to different ( respective ) files.

Issue is if I do it via `widget` how Will I pass data. What I am using is `methodBuilder` way. is this right way to do it ?

code -> profile page body:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'nick_name.dart';
import 'profile_form.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  PageController _pageControler;
  String nickkname,
      firstName,
      middleName,
      lastName,
      gender,
      phoneNumber,
      panNumber;
  List<Widget> _pageList = [
    buildNickNameUI(),
    buildProfileFormUI(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: PageView(
        controller: _pageControler,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: _pageList,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

code: -> nickName page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Container buildNickNameUI() => Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
    );
```

code: -> profileForm page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


Container buildProfileFormUI() => Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    );
```

is this the right way and follows best practice ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate dart file for each section and have something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'

class SectionName extends StatelessWidget {
    String arg1, arg2, arg3;

    SectionName(this.arg1, this.arg2, this.arg3) // Constructor with arguments

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            color: color
        );
    }
}
```

You can then import the individual files and use them in your pageView.

Comment: and what about the values from this stateless widget like for e.g if its a text field and main file have the form element...

Comment: I don't understand your question